# Application Insight Custom Metrics Not available in Logs

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I had loaded Custom Metrics using App Insights API to Application Insights (which is workspace-based). I want to enrich the custom metrics with tables in logs.However i am not able to see the custom logs in the Log Analytics workspace or in the custom metrics explorer.
Is there a workaround for doing this.

I can create charts using the metrics loaded in Application Insights

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to query the data in the custom tables using Application Insights Metrics Explorer.

Here's an example in Python with the [azure-monitor-opentelemetry](https://pypi.org/project/azure-monitor-opentelemetry/) package from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python):

```py
import os
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace

appi_key = os.environ['APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING']

configure_azure_monitor(
    connection_string=appi_key,
)

tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

with tracer.start_as_current_span("hello"):
    print("Hello, World!")

input()
```

Metrics should appear for query in a near-realtime fashion (couple of seconds), however, the time it will take for metrics to show up for query can depend on several factors. Here is the [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-custom-overview#latency-and-storage-retention):

> A newly added metric or a newly added dimension to a metric might take up to 3 minutes to appear. After the data is in the system, it should appear in less than 30 seconds 99 percent of the time.

Here is where it will show up:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Few of the reasons why custom metrics are not being logged were:**

- There can be couple of minutes or less latency in ***Application Insights*** Pipeline itself. Please check this [AzureMonitorStatus Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor-status/bg-p/AzureMonitorStatusBlog) contains most AI Issues with their resolutions at one place (tech community category).
- When `new custom property` or `new custom metric` is added, it might take for that new field to show up as a field in metadata that the charts use to build themselves, depending on timing.
- If it is a new application, to display that new custom property/metric in metadata, it can take up to `~15 minutes` (maximum) and sometimes less than that.
- Once they are available in Metadata, might need to refresh the portal if you're already in the Metrics Explorer window for that AI resource for it to re-request metadata to see your field (normally just the "refresh" command on Metrics Explorer or an Overview blade is good enough to get that working but doing a full refresh in the browser works as last resort).

Comment: Time windows are much shorter than that, according to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-custom-overview#latency-and-storage-retention